# OSB schema validation performance

Tags: validation, proxy, schema, osb

Is there any performance issues when using Validate nodes in a proxy service inside Oracle Service Bus (OSB)?

What are the best practices when using the Validate node?

What's the time cost of using several Validate nodes, for example:

1. Validate header
2. Branch depending on incomping operation
3. Validate body schema depending on operation
4. Do a xquery transformation
5. Validate schema after transformation
6. Send request to business service

Is it useful a Validate node in step 5 after a xquery? Doesn't a xquery transformation assure schema integrity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Validation does have a performance cost, but generally you validate by default and only reassess when the performance is not sufficient (it's likely that performance gains could be found elsewhere first, by using split-joins, or by rationalising multiple OSB nodes into a single xquery)

Personally, I'd validate the request after the first operational branch (so you know what element to validate against), then, optionally validate the response just before you send it back in the response pipeline.

And no, xquery transforms do not assure schema integrity. I would not recommend validating after your own xquery transformation; the result is within your control so you should be testing that in other ways (ideally, statically), rather than relying on a runtime validation.